# showing link inside a link?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table where when I click on the collumn it shows the
data-detail which works good.

But I would like to make it into a link 
which gives me different results when I change

```
<a class="showdata" data-detail="testing "> john one</a>
```

to

```
<a class="showdata" data-detail="<a id="fav" href="test.cfm?fav" >#dept_loc#</a> "> john one</a>
```

it shows the results wrong.

Is it not possible to put a link inside a link?

Here i put http://jsfiddle.net/62upu25b/2/ .

Answer (score 2):

No. See the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element):

> [**4.5.1 The `a` element**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element)
>
> - [**Categories**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#element-dfn-categories):
>
>   - [Interactive content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#interactive-content-0).
>   - [...]
> - [**Content model**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#element-dfn-content-model):
>     [Transparent](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#transparent), but there must be no [interactive content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#interactive-content-0) descendant.

So [`a`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element) elements are [interactive content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#interactive-content-0), but can't have [interactive content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#interactive-content-0) descendants.

Therefore, you can't place a link inside a link.

Comment: Also, you can't put unescaped HTML into an attribute, which is what the OP appears to be trying.

Comment: While this is all true, it is irrelevant to the question. The question does not use and does not try to use nested `a` elements. Instead, an attribute of an `a` element is a string that will be used to construct a new `a` element (outside the original `a` element). Within an attribute value, a `<` character does not start a tag.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I think I answered the title of the question, but the body of the question asks a different thing.

Answer (score 2):

Whether or not you can have a link inside a link is irrelevant. The problem is that the markup for the second link has double quotes in it, which you can't have inside an attribute. (The quotes interfere with the quotes you used to start and end the attribute value).

You could use single quotes instead:

```
<a class="showdata" data-detail='<a id="fav" href="test.cfm?fav" >#dept_loc#</a> '> john one</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Does this not work for you? http://jsfiddle.net/62upu25b/5/

I added the following:

```
<a class="showdata" data-detail="<a id='fav' href='test.cfm?fav'>#dept_loc#</a>"> 
                john one</a>
```

The problem with your code was that you were placing double quotes within double quotes, which never works. Use single quotes within double quotes instead.